# Detect peaks with two adjacent identical values using pracma::findpeaks

Tags: r

I've got some data with 23 peaks. I've used `pracma::findpeaks` to pick out the peaks. However, one of the peaks has two identical values adjacent each other, at time=7524 and time=7525. It seems `findpeaks` deals with this by ignoring the peak.

Could I please ask if someone could help me make it recognise it. I'd like it to pick out the first of the two peaks, though it would also be good to know how to make it pick out the last of them as well

```
data <- data.frame(time=c(1562, 1563, 1564, 1565, 1566, 1810, 1811, 1812, 1813, 1814, 
                          2058, 2059, 2060, 2061, 2306, 2307, 2308, 2309, 2310, 2560, 2561, 
                          2562, 2563, 2564, 3064, 3065, 3066, 3067, 3580, 3581, 3582, 3583, 
                          3584, 4095, 4096, 4097, 4098, 4099, 4610, 4611, 4612, 4613, 4614, 
                          5128, 5129, 5130, 5131, 5132, 5133, 5637, 5638, 5639, 5640, 5641, 
                          5876, 5877, 5878, 5879, 5880, 5881, 5882, 6125, 6126, 6127, 6128, 
                          6129, 6130, 6607, 6608, 6609, 6610, 6611, 6612, 6613, 7072, 7073, 
                          7074, 7075, 7076, 7077, 7078, 7079, 7519, 7520, 7521, 7522, 7523, 
                          7524, 7525, 7526, 7527, 7528, 7941, 7942, 7943, 7944, 7945, 7946, 
                          7947, 7948, 7949, 8342, 8343, 8344, 8345, 8346, 8347, 8348, 8349, 
                          8350, 8351, 8708, 8709, 8710, 8711, 8712, 8713, 8714, 8715, 8716, 
                          8717, 8718, 9045, 9046, 9047, 9048, 9049, 9050, 9051, 9052, 9053, 
                          9054, 9055, 9352, 9353, 9354, 9355, 9356, 9357, 9358, 9359, 9360, 
                          9361, 9362, 9363, 9624, 9625, 9626, 9627, 9628, 9629, 9630, 9631, 
                          9632, 9633, 9634, 9867, 9868, 9869, 9870, 9871, 9872, 9873, 9874, 
                          9875, 9876),
                   value=c(509, 672, 758, 686, 584, 559, 727, 759, 688, 528, 562, 711, 
                          768, 678, 644, 750, 822, 693, 531, 566, 738, 793, 730, 511, 587, 
                          739, 761, 651, 579, 747, 768, 705, 544, 551, 687, 756, 749, 645, 
                          564, 680, 724, 691, 596, 535, 625, 685, 689, 612, 512, 537, 616, 
                          657, 653, 573, 506, 598, 675, 685, 668, 609, 515, 575, 656, 687, 
                          678, 626, 533, 509, 587, 641, 680, 663, 602, 515, 505, 583, 646, 
                          693, 696, 684, 630, 549, 500, 572, 637, 681, 725, 736, 736, 703, 
                          649, 556, 568, 637, 682, 743, 765, 767, 709, 660, 587, 548, 622, 
                          690, 761, 779, 764, 749, 694, 631, 525, 571, 646, 724, 788, 811, 
                          834, 818, 776, 712, 616, 536, 556, 649, 738, 801, 857, 866, 837, 
                          808, 718, 647, 568, 508, 605, 714, 823, 872, 917, 916, 890, 825, 
                          742, 642, 543, 549, 656, 766, 851, 921, 947, 951, 892, 830, 730, 
                          617, 586, 675, 760, 804, 816, 795, 740, 690, 613, 522))


peaks <- data.frame(findpeaks(data$value, npeaks=23, threshold=100, sortstr=TRUE))
data$n <- seq(1,length(data$value))
data <- merge(x=data, y=peaks, by.x="n", by.y="X2", all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)

ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=value)) +
  geom_col(fill="red") +
  geom_point(aes(x=time, y=X1))
```

[image]

Comment: From what package is `findpeaks`?

Comment: pracma:  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/findpeaks

Comment: Use `peakpat = "[+]{1,}[0]*[-]{1,}"` as described in the linked post ("_If you wanted to also include the first unsustained peak, you could do use `[0]*` instead_"). `findpeaks(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1), peakpat = "[+]{1,}[0]*[-]{1,}")`

Comment: Thank you, could I ask where the linked post you referred to is? Thanks

Comment: You find the links on top of your post.